Html Webpage Labels Relative to Dropdowns
Creating a HTML webpage where I want to position several dropdowns all in specific locations while also having a label displayed overhead relative to the position of the individual dropdowns.
Here my initial attempt I think my problem might be the structure of the classes but not sure.


.dropdown-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  /* Gap between grid items */
}

.shift1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0px;
}

.utility1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0px;
}

.kiwi1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0px;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
}
<form id="create">
  <section>
    <nav>
      <div class="dropdown-container">

        <label for="shift1" class="label">Shift</label>
        <select class="shift1" id="shift1" name="shift1" onchange="dropDownShift()">
          <option disabled selected value="0"> -- Shift -- </option>
          <option value="1"> Shift 1 </option>
          <option value="2"> Shift 2 </option>
          <option value="3"> Shift 3 </option>
          <option value="4"> Shift 4 </option>
        </select>

        <label for="utility1" class="label">label 1</label>
        <select class="utility1" id="utility1" name="utility1" onchange="removeOption('utility',1 ,1)">
          <option disabled selected value="0"> -- U -- </option>
        </select>
        <label for="kiwi1" class="label">label 2</label>
        <select class="kiwi1" id="kiwi1" name="kiwi1" onchange="removeOption('kiwi', 1, 1)">
          <option disabled selected value="0"> -- KW(2) -- </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <input type="submit" value="CLEAR">
  </footer>
</form>




" label displayed overhead relative to the position of the individual dropdowns" - That's not the way positioning works. It would make more sense to position the labels and position the dropdowns in relation to the labels. For that the dropdowns need to be inside the labels.

It would also be useful to know what this is *supposed to look like.


Step 1: Wrap every label and select tag pairs in a div element.
Step 2: Position these div elements as relative and position every label elements as absolute.
Step 3: Keep the select elements static. Finally, adjust the top & left properties to achieve the desired UI.

Sample:


div {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 30px;
}

select {
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
<div>
    <label for="fruit">Select a fruit:</label>
    <select id="fruit">
        <option value="kiwi">Kiwi</option>
        <option selected value="cherry">Cherry</option>
    </select>
</div>



